# Opening a .car file

Tags: file

I'm trying to backwards engineer some code, but some of the code I need is inside a .car file.

If I do a word search I see text inside, but If I open it in Sublime Text I get 90,000 lines of:

7261 6301 0100 0000 a00a 0000 4b00 0000

And if I open it in Notepad++ I get some text along with weird symbols with words like: NULL, EOT, BS, BEL

How do I open this file?

I am not 100% sure of what is in the file. It SHOULD be just plain text code as far as I know but I'm not sure.

Comment: http://file.org/extension/car

Comment: To be frank, I dont see how any of those programs will work. How is software for designing cards and printing going to help me? I'm trying to open a data file that contains game code.

Comment: Despite the fact that it was deleted. It was nice to see a stack overflow user that actually cared about answering the OPs question rather than just enforcing SO's absurdly ridiculous question asking standard. Props to the answerer!